# Cake View wont update when changed

Tags: cakephp, code-generation

I baked a Model, Controller, View by console.
Then I changed the content of View/xxx/index.ctp but the changes are not comitted to the webpage.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

*EDIT*: no cache used

---

**View/Logs/index.ctp**

```
<div class="logs index">
    <h2><?php echo __('SystemLogs');?></h2>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>    
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('isError');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('timestamp');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('category');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('action');?></th>
            <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('detail');?></th>

    </tr>
    <?php

    foreach ($logs as $log): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 
            if (($log['Log']['isError'] == 1){
                echo h("ERR");
            }else{
                echo h("NFO");
            }

        ?>&nbsp; </td>

        <td><?php echo h($log['Log']['id']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($log['Log']['timestamp']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($log['Log']['category']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($log['Log']['action']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><?php echo h($log['Log']['detail']); ?>&nbsp; <br>
            (User: <?php echo h($log['Log']['userID']); ?>)<br>
            (PersID: <?php echo h($log['Log']['PersonalID']); ?>)
        </td>

    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <p>
    <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->counter(array(
    'format' => __('Page {:page} of {:pages}, showing {:current} records out of {:count} total, starting on record {:start}, ending on {:end}')
    ));
    ?>  </p>

    <div class="paging">
    <?php
        echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
        echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Model/Log.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Log Model
 *
 */
class Log extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */

    var $order = "Log.timestamp desc";
    public $displayField = 'detail';
}
```

---

**Controller/LogsController.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Logs Controller
 *
 */

class LogsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Scaffold
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
    var $name = "Logs";
    public $scaffold;


}
```

Comment: Without seeing code, it is rather hard to say .. perhaps edit this to include the relevant bits? This is likely to be closed quickly otherwise.

Comment: the content of index.ctp wont be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `index()` action inside `LogsController`.

You can create one like:

```
public function index() {
    $this->Log->recursive = 0;
    $this->set('logs', $this->paginate());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `public $scaffold;` line and your changes will be in effect. Scaffolding means that cake will generate the code for you.